# Connecting 2 existing Org in separate Machines - Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Do you have any idea how am I going to connect 2 existing organizations from different machines using the existing channel of 1 organizations. Here is what I have as of now, Org1 is running in VM1 and Org2 is running in VM2 with both have there own chaincode installed. What I am trying to do is to connect Org2 to Org1 to a channel of Org1. I don't have any idea how am I going to do it since currently the only example that I have is only using the same VM. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect them through the channel.
Suppose that you have already all the url exposed of each components (peer, orderer ..) and that org1 hold the channel. You simply need give to org2 the right to join the existing channel.

Here a guide:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/channel_update_tutorial.html

based on what you said, you should start the tutorial from the section "Generate the Org3 Crypto Material".

Answer (score 0):

To connect organizations on different hosts, you'll need to create a Docker Swarm. Once you have all the hosts joined to docker swarm, you'll need to create an overlay network and make your containers join this overlay network.

You can start following [this blog](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) that describes a simple configuration for multiple hosts. For further reference, you can refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52307583/4110629).

For deployment using Kubernetes, you can refer to [this medium blog](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-deploy-hyperledger-fabric-on-kubernetes-1-a2ceb3ada078).